# MySQL regex to return matching string only

Tags: mysql

I'm building a query to run in an Invision Power Board hosted site using the SQL Toolbox, unfortunately it seems a but limited and I've not been able to add custom SQL function so far. I've built a mutli-table query but for the sake of simplicity will simplify it here.

The following is a sample of the database and a query to find profiles which include an address in their About Me (field_11) profile using Regex. The results shows the entirety of the About Me  and not just the matching string.

Is there a way to structure the query to return just the matching string found by regex without using a bespoke MySQL function?

SQL Database

```
CREATE TABLE core_pfields_content
    (`field_11` LONGTEXT);

INSERT INTO core_pfields_content
    (`field_11`)
VALUES
    ('<p> C++ eveloper</p> <p> AJ4ndBBLJZmRDVtC7JfGAVivhUXFDvWqKL </p>'),
    ('<p> Norwegian designer and illustrator working out of Oslo. </p>'),
    ('<p> Hello everyone, I am a Freelancer Photographer </p> <p> My portfolio: </p> <p> address: AW7fvzoEWAfiyyEwgXmgog525NCCeAxVmG </p>');
```

Query

```
SELECT field_11
FROM core_pfields_content
WHERE field_11 REGEXP '^.*([A][a-km-zA-HJ-NP-Z1-9]{26,33}).*';
```

Result

```
field_11
<p> C++ eveloper</p> <p> AJ4ndBBLJZmRDVtC7JfGAVivhUXFDvWqKL </p>
<p> Hello everyone, I am a Freelancer Photographer </p> <p> My portfolio: </p> <p> address: AW7fvzoEWAfiyyEwgXmgog525NCCeAxVmG </p>
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02d1d/1

Comment: [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/) and [SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-reference) are different software packages produced by different companies. Even if both implement SQL, they extend it in different ways and sometimes use different syntax conventions that render the queries incompatible between them. Please use the correct tags.

Comment: @axiac title says MySQL - we now know which one is correct

Comment: @Eli of course we know which one is correct. It says MySQL in the question body and the posted queries do not look like SQL Server at all. The purpose of my previous comment is to raise awareness of the new and also existing [so] users that, too many times, tag a question as "SQL Server" without reading what the "SQL Server" tag stands for.

Comment: @axiac I knew that - when possible, I drop a comment as you do, and then go ahead and remove the incorrect tag. This time the edit queue was full :(